# Rails server won't run - Could not find gem error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, ruby-on-rails-4, terminal

When running the rails s command from my terminal (Mac OSX Yosemite) I'm getting the following error:

```
Could not find mime-types-2.4.3 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

When I run bundle install I get 'Using mime-types 2.4.3'

```
Using rake 10.4.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.2
Using minitest 5.5.1
Using thread_safe 0.3.4
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using activesupport 4.2.0
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile 0.6.2
Using nokogiri 1.6.6.2
Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.5
Using loofah 2.0.1
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.1
Using actionview 4.2.0
Using rack 1.6.0
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using actionpack 4.2.0
Using globalid 0.3.3
Using activejob 4.2.0
Using mime-types 2.4.3
Using mail 2.6.3
Using actionmailer 4.2.0
Using activemodel 4.2.0
Using arel 6.0.0
Using activerecord 4.2.0
Using debug_inspector 0.0.2
Using binding_of_caller 0.7.2
Using coffee-script-source 1.9.1
Using execjs 2.3.0
Using coffee-script 2.3.0
Using thor 0.19.1
Using railties 4.2.0
Using coffee-rails 4.1.0
Using hike 1.2.3
Using multi_json 1.10.1
Using jbuilder 2.2.8
Using jquery-rails 4.0.3
Using bundler 1.7.12
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using sprockets 2.12.3
Using sprockets-rails 2.2.4
Using rails 4.2.0
Using rdoc 4.2.0
Using sass 3.4.12
Using sass-rails 5.0.1
Using sdoc 0.4.1
Using spring 1.3.2
Using sqlite3 1.3.10
Using turbolinks 2.5.3
Using uglifier 2.7.0
Using web-console 2.0.0
```

But running the 'rails s' command again results in the same error message:

```
Could not find mime-types-2.4.3 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Here's the gemfile (the default one w my Rails 4.2 created):

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Note - mime-types 2.4.3 is located in the Gemfile.lock

Any ideas as to what the problem might be?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Try `bundle update mime-types`. If nothing works, share the Gemfile so that we can look at it. Thanks

Comment: I've run bundle update mime-types. Same error persists. I've added the gemfile (it's the one that the 'rails new appname' command generated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try bundle install --path vendor/cache

Comment: try `bundle install --path vendor/cache`

Comment: The problem persists if I create a new rails application - any ideas as to why?

Comment: are you still using the "mime" gem?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
bundle update mime-types
```

then run server again.

Comment: Tried that - same error persisted. Ran bundle install --path vendor/cache as suggested by Dylan Little and it worked.